# Pylab is not installing on my macbook

Tags: python, macos, numpy, osx-mountain-lion

MITX 6.00 pylab is not installing on my macbook running mountain lion running python 2.7.3. I have tried installing it multiple times but I can not get it to work. I have posted the error message below but am not sure what it is telling me to do. If you could explain this error and how I fix it that would be great.

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> import pylab

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    import pylab
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from matplotlib.cbook import MatplotlibDeprecationWarning
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 29, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_bbcfcf6_20130307-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/numpy/__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_bbcfcf6_20130307-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_bbcfcf6_20130307-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_bbcfcf6_20130307-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_bbcfcf6_20130307-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import multiarray
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_bbcfcf6_20130307-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_bbcfcf6_20130307-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/numpy/core/multiarray.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
>>>
```

Comment: It's telling you you have libraries for the wrong architecture installed.  Looks like your real problem is not getting `numpy` installed correctly.

Comment: Enthought has a downloadable package for OSX [here](http://www.enthought.com/products/epdgetstart.php?platform=mac) that should work for you.

Comment: Based on those paths, you've obviously installed some additional Python 2.7, besides the one that came with OS X. You have to tell us which one you installed, and how you installed it, before we can give you exact specifics on the solution.

Comment: @mtadd This is the result after installing Enthought.

Answer (score 1):

You should try 64bit version of this Enthought.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the important bits from that message are the following

```
ImportError: dlopen( [long path to] multiarray.so, 2): no suitable image found.
Did find: [same path to] multiarray.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

So basically, did you install it correctly? Meaning, the correct architecture (x86, x64 depending on your version of Python).

Comment: what do u mean by "version of Python"? Idle version 2.7.3 and I installed Enthought 32bit